# Help to prove a conjecture (recurrence)

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

Establishing a sequence by the following recurrence:

$C_1=1$

$C_2=3$

$C_{n+2}=C_{n+1}+C_n$

It looks like Fibonacci sequence, but we obtain very different numbers. I observed two things that I want to prove, but I couldn't figure it out.

**First:** If $n$ is a prime number, then $n|C_n-1$. I find this impressive because the tests that I did with the odd numbers that is not prime, $n$ does not divide $C_n$. I tested all odd numbers until $51$.

**Second:** if $m$ and $n$ is prime numbers, then $gcd(C_m,C_n)=1$. A corollary is that the numbers of primes is infinity. I tested until $n=71$. (this statemente in Fibonacci sequence is true)

**Third:** if $n$ is a prime number, then $C_n$ is only divisible by primes greater than $n$. (also, this statemente in Fibonacci sequence is true)

The problem is that some statements that is true in Fibonacci sequence are not true in this sequence, like: If $m|n$, the $F_m|F_n$. Or, $gcd(F_m,F_n)=F_{gcd(m,n)}$. This statementes are not true in this sequence. And without some tools it's hard to prove something substantial. (sorry for my english)

Comment: We have $C_{n+2} - C_{n+1} - C_n = 0$, so we try $C_n = \lambda^n$ giving $\lambda^2 - \lambda - 1 = 0$ so that $2\lambda_{1,2} = 1 \pm \sqrt{5}.$ Hence our general solution is $C_n = A\lambda_1^n + B\lambda_2^n$, now we want to put in our initial conditions $1 = A \lambda_1 + B\lambda_2$ and $3=A\lambda_1^2 + B\lambda_2^2$.

Comment: I did that, but I didn't see this helping to prove those statements,

Comment: Ever heard of Lucas numbers? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number

Comment: This is relevant, too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test

Comment: This is called the Lucas sequence. Let $F_n$ be the $n$th Fibonacci number : $F_0=0, F_1=1,$ etc. Then $C_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n+1}.$ .... If $p$ is prime  and $p\ne 5$ then $ p$ does  divide $C_{n-1}.$  But  $5$ does not divide any $C_n.$  The sequence of remainders of $C_n$, modulo $5,$  is $1,3,4,2,1,3,4,2,1,3,4,....$     Also we have $C_n+C_{n+2}=5 F_{n+1}.$

Comment: I don't see how $\gcd(C_m,C_n)=1$ when $m,n $ are unequal primes  implies that there is no largest prime.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet You have to assume that the  number of primes are finite, if $m,n$ are prime numbers, $gcd(C_m,C_n)=1$, so every $C_p$, with $p$ prime, have to divisible for a prime or a power of only one prime, otherwise, we will have more primes than $p$, this contrandicts the pigeonhole principle. The idea is this one: [link](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/FibonacciPrimes.shtml)

Comment: Thank you. The first chapter of the book Prime Number Records lists about 23 different proofs that there is no largest prime, or that the set of primes (if it exists) is infinite. (one proof is topological). But not this one. I recently saw another one on this site.